# Save and keep dropdown values after page refresh PrimeNG

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

How can I save and keep the dropdown value of the dropdown item of PrimeNG after page refresh ?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

**HTML**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities2" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity2" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```

**TypeScript**

```
   import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

    interface City {
      name: string;
      code: string;
    }

    export class MyModel {
        cities2: City[];
        selectedCity2: City;

        constructor() {
            //An array of cities
            this.cities2 = [
                {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
                {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
                {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
                {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
                {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
            ];
        }
       ngOnInit(){
        localStorage.setItem('key', this.selectedCity2);
        const getItem = localStorage('key');
        this.selectedCity2 = getItem;


    }
```

Comment: This question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77264800/15563603
additionally it is to use a service file, set the value of the dropdown at ngOnDestroy to the file and to subscribe to it to get the data on ngOnInit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, to set (or get) a javascript object in (or from) localStorage, use `JSON.stringify` (or `JSON.parse`) method.

Then, in `ngOnInit` method, you should only get the value stored in your localStorage and you must not update it as it is in your code.

So this method becomes :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    // get localStorage value
    this.selectedCity2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
  }
```

Finally, everytime you select an item in your *dropdown* element, you have to update its value in the localStorage like that :

```
  saveInLocalStorage() {
    // update localStorage value
    localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(this.selectedCity2));
  }
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yd1vp6)

Comment: Hi, I just tried it out in my applicaition and I am getting following error warn argument of type string | object is not assignable to parameter of type string. Type OBject is not assignable to type string. If I delete JSON.parse then the warning will be not shown but it is not working then

Comment: Ok, after save into localstorage the data looks like this if I get it: {'key:1, name:'Ney York', type:0, validFrom:"2002-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"} but still not working

Comment: Did you add `(onChange)="saveInLocalStorage()"` in your HTML ?

Comment: Thtat's already saved in localstorage, you should not save that again.

Comment: No, it isn't. PrimeNG does not save data in your localstorage for you. It's your job to do it.