# How to retain the data in previous page when navigating back to that page from a different one?

Tags: angular

I'm using 4 components and in each of the components there will be 'next'(not in the last) and 'previous'(not in the first) button. After clicking on Next button , it will navigate to the next component. But when I navigate back to the previous component , the data that I have entered in the fields are no longer available. I need to retain the data when navigating to previous pages.

I have been searching a solution for this, but couldn't find one. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Store data in localStorage and load the same from it when you leave or enter components

Comment: As mentioned, localStorage is an option if you want to retain the data on browser reload. And if that's not necessary, a regular service should do the trick just fine.

Comment: a better way is to use shared data service

Comment: Can anyone of you provide a sample code  with a single input field for this functionality?It will be really helpful since I'm new to angular.

Comment: @SuryaPrakash Honestly, I'd recommend taking Angular's Tour of Heroes tutorial to get you started with the basics (see https://angular.io/tutorial). The tutorial covers services among other things. And if you're still stuck afterwards and have some code to show us, we can help you.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I successfully implemented the functionality using a service.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a simple example how you can retian data even after returning from other page, (note: on browser reload the date will be lost):

assume you are creating a form on ngOnInit() lifecycle hook:

```
registerForm: FormGroup;
createForm() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: [],
    });
}
```

now how will we handle this:

```
    import { DataStoreService } from './data-store.service';
    constructor( private dataStoreService: DataStoreService) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createAndLoadForm();
    }
    createAndLoadForm() {
    const savedFromState = this.dataStoreService.getPaymentScheduleFormState();
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: [savedFromState ? savedFromState.amount : ''],
    });
  }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.dataStoreService.setPaymentScheduleFormState(this.registerForm.value);
      }
```

and we will create a new file as below

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataStoreService {
    private paymentScheduleFormState: any;

    constructor( ){ }

    setPaymentScheduleFormState(formState: any) {
        this.paymentScheduleFormState = formState;
    }

    getPaymentScheduleFormState() {
        return this.paymentScheduleFormState;
    }
}
```

So basically any time the user navigates to other page ngOnDestroy hook will be called and you set the value. While creating the form next time when user comes it will first check whether the service returns a value alse use default value.
Additionally you can reset the value of the form on submit or whenever its appropriate using

```
this.registerForm.reset();
```